# Faster way of replacing text in all dom elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-traversal

I'm trying to replace all text in between tags and I want to know the fastest way of doing so.

An example would be trying to replace all text with the arbitrary string helloWorld, so that this:

```
<div>
    <div>
        RandomText1
        <div>
            RandomText2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Becomes this:

```
<div>
    <div>
        helloWorld
        <div>
            helloWorld
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My current approach would be :

- Do Depth-first search (DFS) on DOM
- For each element parse and determine which part is text and which part is an element.
- For the part that is text replace it.

This to me would be really slow, especially trying to do this for a large document and having to repeat the process many times. Is there a faster way?

Comment: Use `TreeWalker`.

Comment: Or `nodeIterator`

Comment: You can use the concept of bubbling in Js for this approach

Comment: I'll double check both treeWalker and nodeIterator. Am I correct in assuming I'll receive back a list of all the nodes in document order, so I don't have to do the traversing? If so I could iterate through that list and do my replacement thing on each element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to parse each element to find text nodes, you can just recursively traverse [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) property of an element

```js
var newText = 'hello world';
function replaceTextNodes(node) {
  node.childNodes.forEach(function(el) {
    if (el.nodeType === 3) {  // If this is a text node, replace the text
      if (el.nodeValue.trim() !== "") { // Ignore this node it it an empty text node
        el.nodeValue = newText;
      }
    } else { // Else recurse on this node
      replaceTextNodes(el);
    }
  });
}

var onClick = replaceTextNodes.bind(null, document.querySelector('#container'));
document.querySelector('#replace').addEventListener('click', onClick);
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div>
    RandomText1
    <div>
      RandomText2
      <ul>
        <li>RandomText3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="replace">Replace</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [***TreeWalker***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) object as the most fast tool for DOM traversal.
A *TreeWalker* can be created using the [Document.createTreeWalker()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker) method.

```js
function replaceAllText(newText) {
    var walker = document.createTreeWalker(
        document.body,  // root node
        NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,  // filtering only text nodes
        null,
        false
    );
    
    while (walker.nextNode()) {
        if (walker.currentNode.nodeValue.trim())  // if it's not empty(whitespaced) node
          walker.currentNode.nodeValue = newText;
    }
}

replaceAllText("helloWorld");
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
        RandomText1
        <div>
            RandomText2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker

[***Performance test demonstration***](http://jsfiddle.net/zaqtg/10/)

Answer (score 3):

The [`nodeIterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator) is pretty fast. It has no problems with nested nodes no matter how deeply they're buried. Note: added red text that's 6 levels down. Details commented in Snippet.

**SNIPPET**

```js
/* Create a custom filter which will...
||...the 3rd parameter of createNodeIterator method...
*/

function textFilter(node) {
  // if .nodeType is 3 (3 is text, 1 is element)
  if (node.nodeType === 3) {
    // Set .nodeValue to 'hellowWorld'
    node.nodeValue = 'helloWorld';
    // Return NodeFilter object to accept node
    return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
  }
  // Otherwise ignore node
  return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
}

function findText() {
  // Reference the rootNode
  var content = document.querySelector('body');

  /* Create nodeIterator passing
  || content or rootNode
  || NodeFilter object or WhatToShow property
  || Custom filter function
  */
  var iterator = document.createNodeIterator(content, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, textFilter);
  // Advance to the next sibling or descend to node's children nodes 
  var node = iterator.nextNode();
  // While there is a node...
  while (node) {
    // ...Go on to it...rinse, lather, and repeat
    node = iterator.nextNode();
  }

}

findText();
```

```css
.mark {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    RandomText1
    <div>
      RandomText2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class='mark'>
            6 Deep!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    RandomText1
    <div>
      RandomText2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    RandomText1
    <div>
      RandomText2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    RandomText1
    <div>
      RandomText2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    RandomText1
    <div>
      RandomText2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

DOM searching done by the browser is very fast, and it optimized also.
So, I would suggest to add some common class on the DOM elements which need to be changed and then manipulate them using that class identifier.

Also,

FYI, `document.getElementById()` works on DFS and is pretty efficient.

Comment: He does not want to do "DOM searching", and he does not want to change certain elements. He wants to deal with **all** text nodes. Why would he need `document.getElementByid`?

Comment: Yes, I don't see the reason to add id's to every node. I want to traverse the dom and then change the internal text

Comment: I am not saying you to do it with document.getElementById().

I was giving suggestion that brower uses DFS only, so you can go ahead with DFS. (that is why I have put FYI).

Answer (score 0):

Loop over your HTML than find nodeValue like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(function(o,i){
    console.log(o.firstChild && o.firstChild.nodeValue);
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q7ewbswx/